# Why providers are not tree shakable by default?

Tags: angular, ivy

When a service is provided inside a module but no used anywhere, why isn't it tree shaken by default as Angular does with components? Even if component is declared inside a module it will not be included in bundle if it won't be used somewhere e.g. as selector.

Some will say that it is because we already imported a service inside that module, we created an import statement but we did exactly the same in case of component which is tree shakable so what's the difference? At the step of compilation Angular can see whether the service has been injected somewhere. I know that just providing a service inside a module means that's the service is already injected in the Root Injector but still I can't treat it as a satisfying answer.

Using providedIn: 'root' means that the dependency will be bundled on demand in case there is a need for that during compilation (e.g. some component injects it) and in such case using the providedIn: 'root' I saw plenty of explanations that this way we provide the dependency without creating an import statement in a module.

So again: Why declarations e.g. components even if imported in a module can be tree shaken if not used but dependencies e.g. services can't?

My guess:
It has nothing to do with Angular tree shaking. Unused components are being removed from bundle because in case of not using it we don't create an instance of it and something inside Angular e.g. terser treats it as unused so it removes it entirely from the bundle.

In case of providers as I wrote already providing it in a module means injecting in a Root Injector and to do that Injector creates instance of such service like new MyService(...) so it has to be bundled. But again it doesn't mean that Angular couldn't check if creating such unused service is necessary. So maybe it's just how Angular works?

Comment: You haven't really mentioned what language/framework you ar etalking about. I get it's not Angular.
Also, the question is probably too broad for Stackoverflow and any answer would be opinionated.

Comment: @ilmarinen I tagged this question as angular and ivy from the start

Answer (score 0):

Angular injection is somewhat complex. There could be various declarations that would refer your service it could be done on any node of the injectors tree. For example `{provide: BaseService, useExisting: MyService}`. This way the exact instance which would be injected into the exact place of the application becomes clear only on runtime. Static analysis for that sounds fairly complex and not error prone at all and that is the reason it is not done by the angular team.

Components on the other hand as you've mentioned are placed into modules for transitive compile scopes (to bind the html-tags in the modules' components to the exact classes) and in case there is no real reference, it is easier to exclude them on a static level.

also I would mention the thing that module providers are not the root providers. There are ways to initiate a module for a specific components subtree. Then it's providers will only be injectable in that subtree. The simplest way to achieve that is lazy loading a module by router

```
@NgModule({
  provide: [HttpClientModule] // this way there is a duplicate of the 
    // HttpClient and all of other http stuff in LazyFeature1 subtree, and
    // none of the root module injectors would work 
})
export default class LazyFeature1Module {
}

...
{
  path: 'lazy1'
  loadChildren: () => import('./lazy-feature1')
}
```